# Counts in activerecord query without using sql string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Looking for a proper way to include counts while trying to convert a pure SQL query to Activerecord query. I am not really experienced with Activerecord, so maybe I am missing something obvious here.

The problem is how to include counts in end results without having to use sql query.

Here is what I have so far and it works well. I just want to get rid of the remaining SQL part.

```
    abc has_many :pqr
    pqr has_many :xyz
    ids = [n]

    abc
     .select(
       :identifier,
       :name,
       "count(DISTINCT pqr.key) as pqr_count",
       "count(xyz.id) as xyz_count",
     )
     .joins(pqr: [:xyz])
     .where(
       active: true,
       id: ids,
       xyz: {
         status: 'open',
       }
     )
     .where.not(identifier: 'sandbox')
     .group(:identifier)
```

In short replace `"count(DISTINCT pqr.key) as pqr_count" and "count(xyz.id) as xyz_count"` with something better

Any point in right direction would be really great.

Comment: What's wrong with doing it like this?

Comment: @Iceman: I didn't say there is anything wrong with it. But I would still prefer a complete activerecord solution if possible. It also has a benefit of getting away from hard coding table and column names.

Comment: @Indigo i agree as going pure activerecord solution will also help safeguarding against sql injection attacks. At some point i was also looking for the same.

Comment: @user3775217 Sql injection only happens with user input, there is no user input in the string part of this query.

Comment: @Iceman yes, i was referring to my case, why i was looking for such support once.Thanks

Comment: @user3775217: you are right, same as Iceman, we also converted all pure sql queries to activerecord for this reason. In this particular case, it's not that easy but as part of learning, I want to at least try this query to make complete activerecord.

Comment: @Indigo have u find any solution? as it happens to be i am looking for the same solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use substitute Arel nodes for the part of the select query where there are strings:

```
  abc
     .select(
       :identifier,
       :name,
       PqrModel.arel_table[:id].count(true).as('pqr_count'),
       XyzModel.arel_table[:id].count.as('xyz_count')
     )
     .joins(pqr: [:xyz])
     .where(
       active: true,
       id: ids,
       xyz: {
         status: 'open',
       }
     )
     .where.not(identifier: 'sandbox')
     .group(:identifier)
```